# Getting 504 Gateway Time-out when calling Microsoft Graph Calendar in chunks

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I use Postman it works perfectly. However if I use the same headers in PHP I get a `504 Gateway Time-out` error.

This is how I call the request:

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
    'Cache-Control' => 'private',
    'Transfer-Encoding' => 'chunked',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
    'Vary' => 'Accept-Encoding',
    'x-ms-ags-diagnostic' => '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_12","ADSiteName":"WEU"}}',
    'Preference-Applied' => 'odata.track-changes',
    'OData-Version' => '4.0'
];

$request = $this->guzzle->get('v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime=2019-12-12T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2019-12-13T00:00:00Z', ['headers' => $headers]);
print_r($request->getBody());
```

As soon as I change `Transfer-Encoding` to `chunked` (just like it is in Postman) I get the gateway error. If I don't use it I don't get the calendar events.

Answer (score 0):

I think it got something to do with the `odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;` in the content-type header. With this header you tell Microsoft you want to keep the connection open and receive additional changes. (Which I didn't even know they supported.)

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?view=graph-rest-1.0) you are not required to send those extra headers.